# Writing To Existing XML FILE

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file, that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
  <WhereDoCopy Path="C:\Users\USER\Desktop\jobs" />
</Settings>
```

What can I do, to add an Element to that file?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" - that's what we use tags for here on [SO].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("your.xml");
XElement item = new XElement(WhereDoCopy ,
                new XAttribute("Path", "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\jobs2"));
doc.Root.Add(item);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx